# How do I fix my keyhold commands so that I don't get a "not subscriptable" error?

Tags: python, pygame

I put all the correct key hold commands, and when I run the program it says:

> "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Here's example code:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    x -= vel
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    x += vel
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    y -= vel
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    y += vel
```

By the way, I am using Python 3.
I've already looked up the commands to make sure they're right, and I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: You missed the brackets. It has to be `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your first line to:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Without it, the function itself is being returned to `keys`. Which is why you are getting that error. You want the result of the function, so you need to add the parentheses.